# Issue in generating calendar event using Google zxing api

Tags: events, calendar, zxing, qr-code

I tried to generate calendar event qr code using Google ZXing API but the image generated by it is not recognisable as an event. I used the same data format specified at different websites but it only creates qr code but not as a recognizable event. BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Concert DTSTART:20110912 DTEND:20110912 DESCRIPTION:Metallica concert END:VEVENT Please help me to understand what I am missing. Issue is only for calendar event.

Comment: Can you insert the QR you have created so we can see it?  Which scanner are you using and does it work with other calendar codes?

Comment: Got the issue, I was not using newline after each key value pair without any extra spaces. Now the correct Source is:                  BEGIN:VEVENT\n
SUMMARY:Meeting with Tasneem\n
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20140413\n
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20140415\n
LOCATION:Delhi\n
DESCRIPTION:Important Meeting\n
END:VEVENT